# InputStream wrapper with actual read in a dedicated thread

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream, guava, apache-commons

Asynchronous IO in java was introduced too late and still not all streams support it.

In my case, on Windows there's no way to read or close asynchronously a pipe returned by `java.lang.Process.getInputStream()`.

Building `maven-scm-provider-cvsjava` hangs forever, if a `cvs` binary is available, but exits prematurely. `cvsjava` internally uses the Netbeans cvs client, particularly the [LoggedDataInputStream#read()](https://www.javatips.net/api/openflexo-master/flexodesktop/externalmodels/flexojavacvs/src/main/java/org/netbeans/lib/cvsclient/util/LoggedDataInputStream.java) method. There's a poor man's interruptible read support in it, which saves you when a process hangs and abuses you, when a process crashes.

I need to wrap a stream in a manner so all stream operations are forwarded to a dedicated thread and the caller thread uses `Object.wait()` or `concurrent` API families to wait interruptibly. Are there such streams in Apache commons or in Guava or somewhere else?

Yes, I know that these threads will leak and I'm totally fine with that, because the alternative is main program freeze.

I wrote an example implementation, but I don't want to reinvent a wheel.
https://gist.github.com/basinilya/a5392de106cd890a28742960bcc5cf8c

Comment: Sounds like there's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) hiding behind this question.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I have a negative exp with softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you mean you need to wrap a stream because of a library you're using, you should at least explain the whole situation.

Comment: @Kayaman added `on Windows there's no way to read or close`

Comment: You should really just explain the whole issue, maybe this question can still be salvaged. Explain your problem, explain why you think you need asynchronous support, etc. etc.

Comment: Now that's better.

Comment: Asynchronous I/O was introduced several years ago, and *no* streams support it. There was a thing called AIO from IBM for years, but it was *obsoleted* by the various `Async` classes. Unclear what you're actually asking.